# Tumor Growth Model. Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, differential

I have a calculus question that I can't figure out. Thank you in advance for the help!

A model for tumor growth is the Gompertz function that is a solution to the differential equation

$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = ay\ln\left(\dfrac{K}{y}\right)$ where $y$ is the weight of the tumor in milligrams, $t$ is measured in days, $a$ is a constant, and Upper $K$ is the limiting size of the tumor. Assume that $a = 0.8$ and Upper $K = 100$.

Find a solution to this differential equation that satisfies $y(0) = 1$ mg. enter the exact answer

$y(t)= ..$

Comment: **Hint:** Separation of Variables.

Comment: I knew that was what I needed to do but I'm not good a setting them up. I'm struggling a lot.

Comment: @TimLayerBay Vandalizing  your question like that is unacceptable, please edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y = \frac{K}{u}$ so that

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{K}{u^2}\frac{du}{dt}.$$

Your ODE becomes

$$\frac{du}{dt} = -au\ln u,\quad u(0) = K.$$

By separation of variables,

$$\int \frac{du}{u\ln u} = \int -a\, dt$$

or

$$\ln|\ln u| = -at + C$$

where $C$ is a constant. Hence

$$\ln u = Ae^{-at}$$

where $A$ is a constant. Invoking the initial condition $u(0) = K$, we obtain $A = \ln K$. Thus

$$u(t) = \exp\{e^{-at}\ln K\} = K^{\exp\{-at\}},$$

or

$$y(t) = \frac{K}{u(t)} = K^{1 - \exp\{-at\}}.$$